# Convergence of Fibonacci quotients

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2},~ F_0=0,~F_1=1~$ be the Fibonacci numbers.

Then it is well known that $\lim_n \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

However, many textbooks proved the above by using only the property $S_{n+1}=1+{S_{n}}^{-1}$ where $S_n=\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n-1}}$. I think this proof should first assume the convergence of $S_n$. How can I get the convergence of the quotients?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: One way is to use the closed form for the Fibonacci Numbers:  https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binet%27s_Formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the identity $F_n^2 - F_{n+1}F_{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1}$, we get
$$
\left| \frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}} - \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\right| = \frac{1}{F_nF_{n+1}}\le \frac{F_{n+1}-F_n}{F_nF_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{F_n} - \frac{1}{F_{n+1}}
$$
for $n\ge 2$, so for $m>n\ge 2$ we get
$$
\left| \frac{F_{m+1}}{F_m} - \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} \right| \le \frac{1}{F_n} -\frac{1}{F_m}
$$

You can check that $F_n\to\infty $ as $n\to\infty$, so the above inequality says that $\langle F_{n+1}/F_n\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence.